# Enrich XML document via stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

Our middleware software receives an XML document and forwards it to another software. However, there is one field in the target software (ext_text_10), that I do NOT want to overwrite.

Upon receiving the XML, I would like to call a stored proc, that should query the target database table to find the current ext_text_10 value, and insert a new element in the incoming XML with the resulting value, and then pass it on. This way we will simply pass the current value for that field.
The procedure below is reading the XML, building it again by preserving everything from it, and then inserting one element.

However, it does not return any result. Below is my procedure, and my source XML. 
I hope somebody can tell me what is wrong. This is SQL Server 2016.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[z_ION_GetCurrentCostCenterData] (@xmlData xml)
AS
BEGIN

-- Prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements
SET NOCOUNT ON;
-- Parse XML
DECLARE @parsedXmlData int;
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @parsedXmlData OUTPUT, @xmlData;


DECLARE 

@tenantID varchar(50), 
@acc_entity varchar(3),
@doc_id varchar(50), 
@anl_code varchar(15), 
@anl_dim_id varchar(2), 
@lookup_code varchar(15), 
@anl_code_name varchar(50), 
@prohibit_posting varchar(1), 
@statusCode  varchar(1), 
@anl_cat_id varchar(15), 
@ext_text_6 varchar(50), 
@ext_text_7 varchar(50), 
@ext_text_8 varchar(50), 
@ext_text_9 varchar(50), 
@ext_num_1 varchar(50), 
@ext_num_2 varchar(50), 
@ext_num_3 varchar(50), 
@ext_num_4 varchar(50), 
@ext_num_5 varchar(50), 
@ext_date_1 varchar(50), 
@ext_date_2 varchar(50), 
@ext_fixed_1 varchar(50), 
@ext_fixed_2 varchar(50), 
@ext_fixed_3 varchar(50), 
@TableName NVarchar(255)

  --Get data from XML
  select 
    @tenantID = tenantID,
    @acc_entity = acc_entity,
    @doc_id = doc_id,
    @anl_code = anl_code, 
    @anl_dim_id = anl_dim_id,
    @lookup_code = lookup_code,
    @anl_code_name = anl_code_name,
    @prohibit_posting = prohibit_posting,
    @statusCode = statusCode,
    @anl_cat_id = anl_cat_id,
    @ext_text_6 = ext_text_6,
    @ext_text_7 = ext_text_7,
    @ext_text_8 = ext_text_8,
    @ext_text_9 = ext_text_9,
    @ext_num_1 = ext_num_1,
    @ext_num_2 = ext_num_2,
    @ext_num_3 = ext_num_3,
    @ext_num_4 = ext_num_4,
    @ext_num_5 = ext_num_5,
    @ext_date_1 = ext_date_1,
    @ext_date_2 = ext_date_2,
    @ext_fixed_1 = ext_fixed_1,
    @ext_fixed_2 = ext_fixed_2,
    @ext_fixed_3 = ext_fixed_3

  from OPENXML (@parsedXmlData,'DataArea',2)
  with 
  (tenantID varchar(50) 'Sync/TenantID',
    acc_entity varchar(3) 'Sync/AccountingEntityID',
    doc_id varchar(50) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/DocumentID/ID',
    anl_code varchar(15) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/AnalysisCode',
    anl_dim_id varchar(2) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/AnalysisDimensionId',
    lookup_code varchar(15) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/LookupCode',
    anl_code_name varchar(50) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/Name',
    prohibit_posting varchar(1) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ProhibitPosting',
    statusCode varchar(1) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/Status',
    anl_cat_id varchar(15) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/AnalysisCatID/AnlCat_SHead',
    ext_text_6 varchar(50) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ExtendedAnalysis/ExtensionText6',
    ext_text_7 varchar(50) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ExtendedAnalysis/ExtensionText7',
    ext_text_8 varchar(50) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ExtendedAnalysis/ExtensionText8',
    ext_text_9 varchar(50) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ExtendedAnalysis/ExtensionText9',
    ext_num_1 varchar(50) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ExtendedAnalysis/ExtensionNumber1',
    ext_num_2 varchar(50) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ExtendedAnalysis/ExtensionNumber2',
    ext_num_3 varchar(50) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ExtendedAnalysis/ExtensionNumber3',
    ext_num_4 varchar(50) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ExtendedAnalysis/ExtensionNumber4',
    ext_num_5 varchar(50) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ExtendedAnalysis/ExtensionNumber5',
    ext_date_1 varchar(50) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ExtendedAnalysis/ExtensionDate1',
    ext_date_2 varchar(50) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ExtendedAnalysis/ExtensionDate2',
    ext_fixed_1 varchar(50) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ExtendedAnalysis/ExtensionFixed1',
    ext_fixed_2 varchar(50) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ExtendedAnalysis/ExtensionFixed2',
    ext_fixed_3 varchar(50) 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ExtendedAnalysis/ExtensionFixed3'
    );


  --Create XML to return
  select 
  [EXT_TEXT_10] as 'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ExtendedAnalysis/ExtensionText10'

  from [dbo].[IMT_ANL_CODE_EXT]
      where [ANL_CAT_ID] = @anl_cat_id and [ANL_CODE] = @anl_code
  for XML PATH ('SunSystemsAnalysisCodes'), root('DataArea')


  EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @parsedXmlData

END
```

Source XML:

```
<DataArea xmlns:my="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">
    <Sync>
        <TenantID>INFRA_TRN</TenantID>
        <AccountingEntityID>IMT</AccountingEntityID>
        <ActionCriteria>
            <ActionExpression actionCode="Change" />
        </ActionCriteria>
    </Sync>
    <SunSystemsAnalysisCodes>
        <DocumentID>
            <ID variationID="1495808583000">PRO 00002</ID>
        </DocumentID>
        <IONStatus>
            <Code listID="GenericStatus">Open</Code>
        </IONStatus>
        <AnalysisCode>PRO17</AnalysisCode>
        <AnalysisDimensionId>01</AnalysisDimensionId>
        <LookupCode>Informatiesyste</LookupCode>
        <Name>Informatiesysteem Relatics 10</Name>
        <ProhibitPosting>0</ProhibitPosting>
        <Status>0</Status>
        <AnalysisCatID>
            <AnlCat_SHead>COST CENTRE</AnlCat_SHead>
        </AnalysisCatID>
        <ExtendedAnalysis>
            <ExtensionText6>SVE</ExtensionText6>
            <ExtensionText7>Open</ExtensionText7>
            <ExtensionText8 />
            <ExtensionNumber1>81700</ExtensionNumber1>
            <ExtensionNumber2 />
            <ExtensionNumber3 />
            <ExtensionNumber4 />
            <ExtensionNumber5 />
            <ExtensionDate1>01012016</ExtensionDate1>
            <ExtensionDate2>31122016</ExtensionDate2>
            <ExtensionFixed1>1</ExtensionFixed1>
            <ExtensionFixed2>2</ExtensionFixed2>
            <ExtensionFixed3>2</ExtensionFixed3>
        </ExtendedAnalysis>
    </SunSystemsAnalysisCodes>
</DataArea>
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not clear to me... The XML you provide does not include a `ext_text_10` at all.  The `FOR XML PATH` query at the end will not return the *enriched* XML but just one single field... Did you try to shorten this for  brevity? If I get this correctly you want to XML unchanged, but you want to add one element, which is called `<ExtensionText10>` into `<ExtendedAnalysis>`. Correct? Might this element exist before? Is the position withing the node order relevant?

Comment: btw: `FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated and should not be used any more (rare exceptions exist). Rather use the appropriate [methods the XML data type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

Comment: Hi, yes, the ext_text_10 will not exist in the source XML, the procedure must insert the element, with the value coming from the SELECT statement. I have not shortened for brevity, I was expecting this procedure to return the full XML including the new element. The position does not matter inside the node. I tried to use your solution but I am not able to make it work, which parts of the current procedure can I remove to be able to insert your code? Much appreciate your help! thanks!

Comment: thanks! your comments pointed me in the right direction, all is working now! much appreciated

Comment: Glad to help you! Thx for the acceptance check! If you don't mind, and as you seem to like my answer, it would be nice to - additionally - tick the upvote. TIA and bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this doesn't help you, please answer the questions from my comment below your question!

My magic crystall ball tells me, that you might be looking for something like this (shortened for brevity):

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<DataArea xmlns:my="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">
    <Sync>
        <TenantID>INFRA_TRN</TenantID>
        <!-- more elements -->
    </Sync>
    <SunSystemsAnalysisCodes>
        <DocumentID>
            <ID variationID="1495808583000">PRO 00002</ID>
        </DocumentID>
        <!-- more elements -->
        <ExtendedAnalysis>
            <ExtensionText6>SVE</ExtensionText6>
            <ExtensionText7>Open</ExtensionText7>
            <ExtensionText8 />
            <ExtensionNumber1>81700</ExtensionNumber1>
            <ExtensionNumber2 />
            <ExtensionNumber3 />
            <ExtensionNumber4 />
            <ExtensionNumber5 />
            <ExtensionDate1>01012016</ExtensionDate1>
            <ExtensionDate2>31122016</ExtensionDate2>
            <ExtensionFixed1>1</ExtensionFixed1>
            <ExtensionFixed2>2</ExtensionFixed2>
            <ExtensionFixed3>2</ExtensionFixed3>
        </ExtendedAnalysis>
    </SunSystemsAnalysisCodes>
</DataArea>';
```

--This is the content you want to introduce

```
DECLARE @ContentToAdd NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ExtendedAnalysis/ExtensionText10';
```

--This `XML_DML`-statement will insert your content with the given name before the `<ExtensionNumber1>` (**which must exist! Other positions are possible of course**)

```
SET @xml.modify(N'insert <ExtensionText10>{sql:variable("@ContentToAdd")}</ExtensionText10> 
                  before (/DataArea/SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ExtendedAnalysis/ExtensionNumber1)[1]');
```

--Check the output:

```
SELECT @xml;

<DataArea xmlns:my="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2">
  <Sync>
    <TenantID>INFRA_TRN</TenantID>
    <!-- more elements -->
  </Sync>
  <SunSystemsAnalysisCodes>
    <DocumentID>
      <ID variationID="1495808583000">PRO 00002</ID>
    </DocumentID>
    <!-- more elements -->
    <ExtendedAnalysis>
      <ExtensionText6>SVE</ExtensionText6>
      <ExtensionText7>Open</ExtensionText7>
      <ExtensionText8 />
      <ExtensionText10>SunSystemsAnalysisCodes/ExtendedAnalysis/ExtensionText10</ExtensionText10>
      <ExtensionNumber1>81700</ExtensionNumber1>
      <ExtensionNumber2 />
      <ExtensionNumber3 />
      <ExtensionNumber4 />
      <ExtensionNumber5 />
      <ExtensionDate1>01012016</ExtensionDate1>
      <ExtensionDate2>31122016</ExtensionDate2>
      <ExtensionFixed1>1</ExtensionFixed1>
      <ExtensionFixed2>2</ExtensionFixed2>
      <ExtensionFixed3>2</ExtensionFixed3>
    </ExtendedAnalysis>
  </SunSystemsAnalysisCodes>
</DataArea>
```